# SQL Handling Date/Time in UTC

Tags: javascript, sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL to create meetings / events. A meeting will need to be saved as UTC and then shown to end users based on the timezone they are viewing the meetings in.

Since the end user gets to select the time of the meeting, I need to convert that time to UTC. From there, I will just pass the offset from the local user and convert it to their local time.

Here is what I have done which I am guessing is wrong as the results are not correct:

```
-- Declare the local offset
DECLARE @offset INT = '420'

-- Convert a date/time to UTC
SELECT DATEADD(hh, DateDiff(hh, GetDate(), GetUTCDate()), '2015-01-08 17:45:00') AS ConvertedToUTC;

-- Convert a UTC back to local based on offset
SELECT DATEADD(minute, @offset, '2015-01-08 23:45:00.000') AS ConvertedToLocal
```

The convertedUTC = 2015-01-08 23:45:00.000

The convertedLocal = 2015-01-09 06:45:00.000

Example: Bob creates a meeting for Jan 8th, 2015 at 1:00pm and they are located in Arizona. I need to convert that time to UTC so when Jim comes along from Omaha and views the meeting list, it then shows the adjusted time based on his offset.

Any tips on how to handle this correctly?

Comment: I would highly recommend looking into the DATETIMEOFFSET datatype in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the datetimeoffset construct. Or you could just pull the time off the local machine rather than the db server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx

If you want to switch between offsets using this data types, you can use the SWITCHOFFSET() function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be handle this in the data access code rather than the database itself. You're right to store the time in UTC but it should be the application layer that is responsible for displaying the time in the user's locale. If you absolutely MUST do this in the database then use convert functions rather than DATEADD to display the date in the right timezone rather than manipulating it. You didnt mention which DB you are using but for example MySQL has CONVERT_TZ() function that will show the date in the given timezone.

Comment: Thanks I am using SQL Server 2012. Do you know how I can convert the time to local given the offset from UTC then?

Comment: You use the  SWITCHOFFSET() function in SQL Server.